# what is the maximum for the following function?

Tags: calculus

Let $\Gamma(x)$ be the gamma function and $\Psi(x)$ the digamma function.
Define:

$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( (\Psi(x_i) - \Psi(\sum_i x_i))(c_i - x_i) - \log \Gamma(\sum_i x_i) + \log \Gamma(x_i) \right)$

where $c_i$ are constants.

What is the maximum over $x_i \ge 0$ for this function $f(x)$?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: it came up during a derivation.